# Problem the_permalink

Tags: loop, permalinks

Morning everyone, I'm sorry to disturb, but I need help if possible.

The code below I need to publish part of the contents of some pages.

Firstly I have a problem with "the_permalink" despite write the correct address, this is where he wants (see image). Puts for example before H2 and however outside the tag A.

[image: problem the_permalink]

Secondly I would like to filter out and ONLY a few pages with specific ID but have not been able to find a solution. I tried to put it but it does not work.

```
new WP_Query( 'post_type=page&include=30,60' );
```

Code that I used

```
    <?php
// Lista Pagine con the_excerpt e the_post_thumbnail

// Query Pages
   $my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=page' );

// The Loop
   while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
   $my_query->the_post();
   echo '
      <h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>
      <p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>
      <p>' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</p>
      <a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
   endwhile;

   wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`the_permalink()` will echo the content immediately. You can't use it for string concatenation. What is happening is that your permalink gets `echo`ed by `the_permalink()` before the string is finished building, so the permalink ends up in the wrong place.

What you need instead is [`get_the_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink).

Side note: Because [PHP's `echo` will take multiple parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), separating your strings with a comma (argument delimiter) rather that a period (concatenation operator) should also work:

```
echo '
  <h2>' , get_the_title() , '</h2>
  <p>' , get_the_excerpt() , '</p>
  <p>' , get_the_post_thumbnail() , '</p>
  <a href="' , the_permalink() , '">' , get_the_title() , '</a>';
```

If you do it that way, *every* component of the string `echo`s immediately. You are never concatenating a string so things never get out of order.

As far as excluding pages, you want `posts__in` not `include` but that requires, or limits the query to, the specified post IDs. To exclude, you want `posts__not_in`. And don't use the "query var" syntax. It will trip you up. Use an array like this from example from the Codex:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
  array( 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'post__not_in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) 
  ) 
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... fast and running

With regard to the selection of only a few pages you have any suggestions?
thanks again

Comment: Super SuperYou really are VERY helpful and knowledgeable.
I owe you a coffee
Thank you so much again

Comment: You're welcome but "thanks" is what the "upvote" arrow is for :) and if this solved the question please [mark it as "Accepted"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). Look for the check mark on the left.